# function for different distribution curves

Tags: matlab

I want to make a Matlab function to draw different distribution curves on the histogram of given data and calculate the bins
this's the code I wrote

```
function [] = draw(Data,type)
Count=numel(Data);
bins=int64(sqrt(Count));
h=histfit(Data,bins,type)
end
```

This function gives error:

Error using  * 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in histfit (line 90)
y = area * pdf(pd,x);

Error in draw (line 4)
    h=histfit(Data,bins,type
Can any one help?
Thanks.

Comment: the fucntion does not give error, the way the function gets called gives an error. how do you call it? `draw(yourdata,'logistic')` shoudl work.

Comment: @  Ander Biguri- this's how i call it, but it gives error "Error using hist
Too many input arguments."

Comment: Error using hist? it should be histfit right? Can you post a minimal example with example data that reproduces this error?

Comment: Edit your question with that information

Comment: @Ander Biguri I've edited the question

Comment: Change `bins=int64(sqrt(Count));` to `bins=round(sqrt(Count))`

Comment: @Ander Biguri It's working now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you re rounding "C style", by casting to int, while MATLAB works generally with doubles.

Instead of using `int64` do:

```
bins=round(sqrt(Count));
```